# Solution to build a 'messages read' type queue system in Redis?

Tags: mysql, algorithm, architecture, redis

I'm not entirely sure Redis is the best tool for something like this, however I think it is possible. Many times there is a message you want to send to all of your users. Almost like a system wide news entry. You want to make sure that the user does not see this message more than once, they should only see it once on login, and after that they should never see that news section until a new entry has been published.

I think keep a table in MySQL that sets a boolean column for every time a user has read a message as an inefficient way of doing this. You can't really archive a table like that, because if you do, you won't know what messages a user has read and which they haven't.

It would be great if this can be done completely in memory using Redis pub/sub. What are some strategies for a messages read type system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you could leverage redis pub/sub capabilities and maybe use socket.io for comet – the server pushes messages down to the client. If thats what you want to do I can elaborate a bit more about it, but I´m not entirely sure if the system has to be that complicated for your usecase. Implementig it all from frontend to backend with pubsub/comet is not an easy task, although doable and sometimes required/the right solution for the problem.

How about a simpler approach that might work out for you, too:

Create a `news` table with a `creation_date` datetime field. Add a `last_seen_news_date` field to your `user` table, set it for all users to some date in the past.

When a user loads the page, query the news items like this:

```
select * from news where creation_date > last_seen_news_date_of_user
```

Then update the `last_seen_news_date` with the current datetime or maybe the datetime of the most recent news article.